# Netbeans/Xdebug stopped working

Tags: php, netbeans, xdebug

I have an odd issue with Netbeans/XDebug that doesn't seem to be covered anywhere, and trust me I've looked.  I've been using the combo for well over a year without problems, but monday it just stopped working. I'm getting the dreaded "waiting for connection" message. And no, I haven't made any changes to my computer that might cause this.

The odd part is, this is only on one of my several projects. In all my other projects it's working perfect still. In the various attempts to get it working again in the one project somethings help, like changing from localhost to 127.0.0.1, but it only works once. I'm able to step through the code one time, but any subsequent attempts it just blows through the breakpoints and doesn't connect. Due to that, I'm guessing it's not something specifically with my xdebug settings, but rather something in the project settings itself. But what, is where I'm stumped.

Windows 10
Apache 2.4
Php 5.6
Netbeans 8.2

**php.ini**

```
zend_extension = C:/php56/ext/php_xdebug-2.5.4-5.6-vc11-x86_64.dll
xdebug.idekey = netbeans-xdebug
xdebug.profiler_append = 0
xdebug.profiler_enable = 0
xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger = 0
xdebug.profiler_output_dir = "C:/Apache24/logs/xdebug"
xdebug.profiler_output_name = "cachegrind.out.%t-%s"
xdebug.remote_enable = 1
xdebug.remote_autostart = 1
xdebug.remote_connect_back = 0
xdebug.remote_host = "localhost"
xdebug.remote_port = 9011
xdebug.remote_handler = "dbgp"
xdebug.remote_mode = req
xdebug.remote_log = "C:/Apache24/logs/xdebug/xdebug_remot.log"
xdebug.show_local_vars = 9
xdebug.trace_output_dir = "C:/Apache24/logs"
```

**Netbeans PHP -> Debugging info**

> Debugger port: 9011
>   session ID: netbeans-xdebug
>   stop at first line: (checked)

Does anyone have any ideas that might help with this issue?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because although it is programming-related, it is not reproducible.

Comment: it is reproducible, my co-worker just had the exact thing happen.

Comment: *sigh* It is not reproducible from the information you provide. It might as well be your company's network.

Answer (score 0):

if anyone cares this seems to be an issue with session caching. Deleting stored files in the browser (not cookies) will solve the problem however that is tiresome.

The best solution I've found so far is to set **session.cache_limiter** in php.ini to **nocache**. This has solved the problem for me.

```
; Set to {nocache,private,public,} to determine HTTP caching aspects
; or leave this empty to avoid sending anti-caching headers.
; http://php.net/session.cache-limiter
session.cache_limiter = nocache
```